# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'shape' in python

Tags: python

I'm a beginner in python. I try to find out the Krawtchouk moments of the image. However, I get

> AttributeError: `str` object has no attribute `shape`

```
import numpy as np
from krawtchouk import *

K = wkrchkpoly(101,0.5)

X = 'name.jpg'
Q,Kr1,Kr2 = wkrchkmoment_single(X,[0.5, 0.8])
```

Comment: I don't know the API, but I will say that `wkrchkmoment_single` doesn't take a string (file path) as its first argument. From [here](https://github.com/tariqul-islam/Krawtchouk-Polynomials-and-Moments/blob/master/krawtchouk.py), the input should be a numpy array.

Answer (score 1):

Since `wkrchkmoment_single` takes a `numpy.ndarray` as its first argument ([source code](https://github.com/tariqul-islam/Krawtchouk-Polynomials-and-Moments/blob/master/krawtchouk.py)), you could use the PIL library to read your `jpg`, then convert it to a `numpy.ndarray` using [`np.asarray`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.asarray.html) before passing it to `wkrchkmoment_single`.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

img = Image.open("name.jpg")
img.load()
X = np.asarray(img, dtype="int64")
Q,Kr1,Kr2 = wkrchkmoment_single(X,[0.5, 0.8])
```

Since `wkrchkmoment_single` expects a 2D `np.ndarray` as its first argument, corresponding to a grey scale image, you may need to convert your image from colour to grey scale. One way to do this would be by taking the mean across the third axis of the array, i.e.:

```
X = np.mean(np.array(img, dtype="float64"), axis=2)
```

Comment: It shows this type of error..
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: Full stack trace?

Comment: ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-81f5bf32269a> in <module>
      5 img.load()
      6 X = np.asarray(img, dtype="int64")
----> 7 Q,Kr1,Kr2 = wkrchkmoment_single(X,[0.5, 0.8])

/mnt/Image-Filtering/krawtchouk.py in wkrchkmoment_single(X, p)
    110 
    111     """
--> 112     H,W = X.shape;
    113 
    114     Kr1 = wkrchkpoly(W,p[0])

Comment: @RRSH See my update. The function `wkrchkmoment_single` takes a 2D array, so colour images will need to be pre-processed.

Comment: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'int' and 'float'

Comment: Again, please provide the full stack trace so that we can see where the error comes from.

Comment: TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-04b7a0e8f133> in <module>
      7 #X = np.asarray(img, dtype="int64")
      8 X = np.mean(np.array(img, dtype="int64"), axis=2)
----> 9 Q,Kr1,Kr2 = wkrchkmoment_single(X,[0.5, 0.8])

/mnt/Image-Filtering/krawtchouk.py in wkrchkmoment_single(X, p)
    113 
    114     Kr1 = wkrchkpoly(W,p[0])
--> 115     if (H==W & p[0]==p[1]):
    116         Kr2=Kr1;
    117     else:

Comment: How about using `dtype="float64"`?

Comment: same error :TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'int' and 'float'